# Can't mass-assign protected attributes with nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, simple-form

I have 3 models that are nested:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :recipe_ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :recipe_ingredients, :allow_destroy => true

  attr_accessible :description, :name, :preparation, :recipe_ingredients_attributes, :ingredients_attributes
  validates_presence_of :name, :description, :preparation
end

class RecipeIngredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe, :foreign_key => "recipe_id"
  belongs_to :ingredient, :foreign_key => "ingredient_id"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient
  delegate :name, :to => :ingredient, :allow_nil => true

  attr_accessible :ingredient_id, :quantity, :recipe_id, :ingredient_attributes
end

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipe_ingredients
  has_many :recipes, :through => :recipe_ingredients

  attr_accessible :name
end
```

This is my recipe controller:

```
#<snip>
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @recipe }
  end
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(params[:recipe])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @recipe.save
      format.html { redirect_to @recipe, notice: 'Het recept werd aangemaakt.' }
      format.json { render json: @recipe, status: :created, location: @recipe }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @recipe.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
#</snip>
```

This is what my form looks like (using simple_forms and nested_forms gems):

```
= simple_nested_form_for @recipe, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.input :name, :label => "Naam"
  = f.input :description, :input_html => { :class => "span6" }, :label => "Beschrijving"
  = f.input :preparation, :input_html => { :class => "span6" }, :label => "Bereiding"

  = f.simple_fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |ri|
    = ri.input :quantity, :label => "#"
    = ri.input :name, :label => "Ingredient"
    = ri.link_to_remove "ingredient verwijderen"
  %p
    = f.link_to_add "Voeg ingredient toe", :recipe_ingredients

  .form-actions
    = f.submit "Update recept", :class => 'btn btn-primary'
    = link_to t('.cancel', :default => "Annuleer"), recipes_path, :class => 'btn'
```

Whenever I save a recipe, it gives me:
    ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in RecipesController#create
    Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name

This is my stacktrace:

```
Started POST "/recipes" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-15 19:14:38 +0100
Processing by RecipesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"72F9E5Cim3SFlFabViy8p4eF4el+RGtdlPmkuaoBU90=", "recipe"=>{"name"=>"tets", "description"=>"egwrb", "preparation"=>"gwrv", "recipe_ingredients_attributes"=>{"1355595249889"=>{"quantity"=>"21", "name"=>"grsd", "_destroy"=>"false"}}}, "commit"=>"Update recept"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error (Can't mass-assign protected attributes: name):
  app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:54:in `new'
  app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb:54:in `create'
```

I've tried playing with singular/plural but with no luck. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. 
:ingredient_attributes should be accessible, but it seems not to be?

Kind regards,
Steven

Comment: Can you include your controller code and also what the params sent to the controller are? (you can see that in log/production.log)

Comment: @FionaT I updated my post to include the params and controller code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to create an extra set of nested fields. Within the `ri` block you'll need to add

```
- ri.simple_fields_for :ingredient do |i|
  = i.input :name
```

By doing that you correctly set the name for `ingredient` instead of `recipe_ingredient`.

Comment: tyvm, this fixed it for me!
now it won't show the form field but more likely that this is a problem with nested_forms gem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you just have a small typo in your view:

```
= f.simple_fields_for :ingredient do |i|
```

should be

```
= ri.simple_fields_for :ingredient do |i|
```

I noticed that the params hash has ingredient at the top level, when it should be nested under the `recipe_ingredients_attributes`. (You might also need to set `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on `RecipeIngredient`)

Comment: Thank you. I changed both (I'll update main post) but with no luck. Still gives the same error.